# Apply motion to react component Framer-Motion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, framer-motion, pose

I know that I can apply `motion` directly to element/HTMLtag like this:

```
<motion.div>some content</div>
```

But how can I apply it to this?

```
<Comp />
```

Without wrapping it inside another HTML element, like in `React-Transition-Group` library.

Framer API provides `Frame` component, but it acts like permanent additional HTML element with own styling, and it is messing my layout.

Comment: Accept answer should be @Gabi's https://stackoverflow.com/a/72006520/80428

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If anyone comes to this page seeking for the solution of how to apply `motion` from Framer-Motion library to your React Component and **not** the direct DOM element like "div" or "span", here it is:

```
motion.custom()
```

Example of use:

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"

const MotionLink = motion.custom(Link)

return <MotionLink />
```

As for today it is not mentioned in the [official documentation](https://www.framer.com/api/motion/), or it is in someplace deep and hard to find.

I had found it in BUG reports [here](https://github.com/framer/motion/issues/394), there is a [Codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-franklin-605oh) that illustrates my example, created by the person who reported a bug.

## Version 4.1.3 or higher

Edit: As mentioned by @Aleksandr K. below, use the following for Version >=4.1.3:

```
const MotionLink = motion(Link)
```

Comment: very strange! so important feature be so hidden. neverthelsee thanks so mutch for this.

Comment: this does not work anymore with framer motion version 4.1.3

Comment: for version 4.1.3 or above use `motion(Link)`

Comment: The official documentation for [Custom Components](https://www.framer.com/motion/component/#custom-components)

Answer (score 15):

`motion.custom` was deprecated as of [v4.0](https://github.com/framer/motion/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#400-2021-03-18) in favour of `motion(Component)` or `motion("Component")`.

Your code would simply look like this

```
const MotionComp = motion(Comp)

return <MotionComp>some content</MotionComp>
```

Answer (score 8):

Without using any internal fuctions,
You just need **to wrap it with any motion element**:

```
<motion.div>
  <Comp />
</motion.div>
```

You can notice such behavior across examples in the docs, like of [Side Menu example.](https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-side-menu-mx2rw?fontsize=14&module=/src/Example.tsx&file=/src/Example.tsx:1006-1016)

Comment: You can pass Component through props but that's a bad practice, usually you go for `props.children` or HOC, you can read about it in React docs.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer brought me on the right track.

But it was still a hassle to get everything working.

Therefore, I've created a **full working example** of Staggering elements which are React Components.
It can be found on [this Github link](https://github.com/BertCatsburg/Example-FramerMotion-with-React-Components-as-staggedChildren)

This core of the solution looks like this:

```js
import React from 'react'
import {motion} from "framer-motion";

interface ListElementInterface {
  name: string
}

// *** This is the React Component called in the list
// Pay attention to the ref type. Typescript is a b*tch
const ListElement = React.forwardRef(
  (props: ListElementInterface, ref: React.ForwardedRef<HTMLLIElement>) => {
    return (
      <li ref={ref}>{props.name}</li>
    )
  })


export const ReactList = () => {

    const datalist = [
      {name: 'John'},
      {name: "Alex"},
      {name: "Michael"},
      {name: 'Sandra'},
      {name: 'Mary'}
    ]

    const olVariants = {
      show: {
        transition: {
          staggerChildren: 0.2
        }
      }
    }

    const liVariants = {
      hidden: {opacity: 0, x: 100, transition: {duration: 0.5}},
      show: {opacity: 1, x: 0, transition: {duration: 0.5}}
    }


    // You need to create the Motion component.
    // Not possible to do something like <motion.ListElement...
    const FramerMotionListElement = motion(ListElement)

    return (
    <>
      <motion.ol
        variants={olVariants}
        initial="hidden"
        animate="show"
        className="simplelist"
      >
        {
          datalist.map((el) => {
            return (
              <FramerMotionListElement
                variants={liVariants}
                key={el.name}
                name={`React-${el.name}`}
              />
            )
          })
        }
      </motion.ol>
    </>
    )
}
```